# AlarmManager Interval for Android

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, statusbar

This is the code I have so far

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
setRepeatingAlarm();

public void setRepeatingAlarm() {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), (15 * 1000), pendingIntent);
  }

}
```

This is all I am trying to accomplish:  The alarm will not turn on until 30 seconds past every minute.  Once you clear it, it wont comes back on until 30 seconds past the *next* minute.  So if I open the app, and it is 25 second past the minute, it will activate status bar notification 5 second later.  But if it is 40 seconds past, I will have to wait 50 more seconds (into the next minute).  I am not sure how to use the Calendar function to attain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your requirement then you could try something like the following...

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
if (cal.get(Calendar.SECOND) >= 30)
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);

// Do the Intent and PendingIntent stuff

am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation for `AlarmManager`, it says that `RTC_WAKEUP` use time relative to `System.currentTimeMillis()`:

> RTC_WAKEUP    Alarm time in System.currentTimeMillis() (wall clock time in UTC), which will wake up the device when it goes off.

So simply modify your `triggerAtTime` parameter, for instance to start right away:

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 15 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

Then the alarm will be repeatedly fire every 15 seconds.