# AlarmManager fires broadcast instantly

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Problem: My Alarm manager fires instantly.

I have look at the other examples on Stack overflow where people are facing the same problem but i can't seem to figure out why mine is having the same issue. I've put in high values in the timeToFire parameter but still fires instantly.

```
    public void StartAlarm(string title, string message,int id, DateTime timeToBroadcast)
    {   
        var localIntent = new Intent(_context, typeof (NotificationManager));
        localIntent.PutExtra("title", title);
        localIntent.PutExtra("message", shortMessage);
        localIntent.PutExtra("Id", id);

        _mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(_context, id, localIntent, 0);

        var am = (AlarmManager) _context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);

        long timeToFire = SystemClock.CurrentThreadTimeMillis() + 100*1000;

        am.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, timeToFire, _mAlarmSender);
    }
```

these are the other questions that i have reviewed searching for an answer

[AlarmManager Interval for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905391/alarmmanager-interval-for-android)

[why does my alarm go off straight away? (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218768/why-does-my-alarm-go-off-straight-away-android)

[set the time in Alarm manager Android - alarm fired instantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003892/set-the-time-in-alarm-manager-android-alarm-fired-instantly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Android documentation, `AlarmType.RtcWakeup`[1] requires the time be relative to UTC. I believe `SystemClock.CurrentThreadTimeMillis()`[2] is the number of milliseconds elapsed since the thread *started*. I imagine this is what is causing the `triggerAtMillis` value to be treated as in the past, and triggering the alarm immediately, since this value will be very low.

What you really want is to use the standard `System.currentTimeMillis()`[3] method. This will give you the current time relative to UTC, which is what `AlarmManager` expects.

BTW: The C# version of this is `Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis()`

[1] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC_WAKEUP

> public static final int RTC_WAKEUP
>
> Alarm time in System.currentTimeMillis() (wall
>   clock time in UTC), which will wake up the device when it goes off.
>
> Constant Value: 0 (0x00000000)

[2] [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#currentThreadTimeMillis()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#currentThreadTimeMillis%28%29)

> public static long currentThreadTimeMillis ()
>
> Returns milliseconds running in the current thread.
>
> Returns elapsed milliseconds in the thread

[3] [http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)

> public static long currentTimeMillis ()
>
> Returns the current time in milliseconds since
>   January 1, 1970 00:00:00.0 UTC.
>
> This method always returns UTC times, regardless of the system's time
>   zone. This is often called "Unix time" or "epoch time". Use a
>   DateFormat instance to format this time for display to a human.
>
> This method shouldn't be used for measuring timeouts or other elapsed
>   time measurements, as changing the system time can affect the results.
>   Use nanoTime() for that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a mill for your thorough explanation.